# Lubuntu 16.04 → 18.04 breaks the GUI updater

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, lubuntu, update-manager

Two different PCs were upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 (**L**ubuntu).

Bug is the same: auto-updater window pops up as it should, but after clicking „install“ it does not ask for the password, but quietly crashes.

`sudo apt update` + `sudo apt upgrade` seem to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and was using command line to update Lubuntu. Today I decided to reinstall the Software Updater. Turned out, there is no package named "software-updater", so I used this command instead:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall update-manager
```

Then I started the Software Updater - it didn't crash, but requested reboot. After reboot I started the Software Updater - it didn't crash and showed "The software on this computer is up to date."
Will test again in a couple of days.